# Login once with client once to the REST remote app

Tags: spring-boot, resttemplate, activiti

I am developing a REST client (**A**) that talks to the another rest based application (**B**).

Now **B** is a secure application and has login url. When I hit the url using **RestTemplate** I get nothing in response but headers. But after that if I ask for any other resource using **RestTemplate** to app **B** it says **unauthorized**.

Below image shows the **headers**. How can I login once and then use this headers to talk with application **B** using **RestTemplate**. 
[image]
thank you

I also don't have any login code for my rest client app **A**. As it will completely depend on app **B**. So I will not have any local user database for app **A**.

Comment: Are you making a POST request to the login endpoint of B providing the username & password?

Comment: Yes the login call is post. After that I want to make any call GET or POST but not sure what to do with these headers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Request: POST /login username=user&password=password
Response: 302 Set-Cookie: JSESSIONID=xxxxxxx

Request: GET /protected-endpoint Cookie: JSESSIONID=xxxxxxx
Response: 200 Stuff...
```

A successful `POST` request to the `/login` endpoint should return a `JSESSIONID` Cookie.  This is what you'll need to pass along in subsequent requests as this is your session token.

Depending on your Security Configuration you may need to make some modifications but that is the gist of it.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! Can you give one example code how to set cookie in RestTemplate?